# Redirect Non WWW to WWW - htaccess placed in sub-folder

Tags: linux, php, redirection, htaccess

I am working on a site which has `.htaccess` file in root. There is a folder named babynames. This folder also has `.htaccess` file. I need the code to redirect from NON WWW to WWW for this folder. Anybody comes to this folder without www should be redirected to www.

The code at `/babynames/.htaccess` is

---

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /babynames/

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.astrolika.com/babynames/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /babynames/404.php/$1 [L,QSA]


ErrorDocument 404 /babynames/404.php

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

---

Can anybody guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What issue, precisely?

Comment: If i use https without www it does not redirected to www for folder babynames

Answer (score 0):

From the post
[Use htaccess to add www with https support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097542/use-htaccess-to-add-www-with-https-support):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

> The second condition checks if the *HTTPS* environment variable (either `on` or `off`) is set to `on` and captures the appended `s` that is then available with `%1`. If it doesn’t match, `%1` is just an empty string.